# ¿Como selecciono un item menu de navegacion y lo modifico mediante codigo?

Tags: java, android, firebase, navigationview

Necesito tomar un item y modificarlo segun una condicion.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No quiero que el item cambie al hacer click sobre el.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es mi codigo ahora.

```
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.nav_camera) {
        // Handle the camera action
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_gallery) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_manage) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_send) {

    } else if (id == R.id.usuario_Verificado) {

        FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
        boolean emailVerified = user.isEmailVerified();
        if(emailVerified==true) {
            item.setIcon(R.drawable.baseline_verified_user_24);
            item.setTitle("Verificado");
        }
```

Busco cambiar esto

```
    else if (id == R.id.usuario_Verificado) {

        FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
        boolean emailVerified = user.isEmailVerified();
        if(emailVerified==true) {
            item.setIcon(R.drawable.baseline_verified_user_24);
            item.setTitle("Verificado");
        }
```

Comment: **[Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en Español](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour)**. lee 
**[cómo crear una buena pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)** y **[¿sobre qué temas puedo preguntar aquí?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)**. **Debes [edit] tu pregunta** con el código que hayas intentado, errores, etc. Puedes consultar aquí [qué funciones tiene Stack Overflow en Español para que puedas organizar el código o lo que coloques en tus preguntas y/o respuestas](http://meta.es.stackoverflow.com/a/1453/78). Saludos.

Comment: A ver, a ver, quieres que haga lo mismo como si le hicieras click, pero no quieres darle click, es decir, la persona verifica su correo y ¿eso se cambia automaticamente?, porque querrias algo asi en una función de verificación. El tiene que cerrar l'app para ir a verificarse al correo... bien podrias ponerlo al arrancar la actividad y en el resumen. O el que le de click, no es mala idea.

Comment: Quiero decir... no veo lógica en que sea en tiempo real, pero bueno, si quisieras lograr eso, yo se la manera pero es un poco larga, ya que el autentification, no es en tiempo real como el firebasedatabase y el FireStore

Comment: como estas claudio, me podrias detallar cual seria el problema que te surge al hacer lo que hiciste ? muchas gracias

Comment: @GastónSaillén No hay problemas, la idea seria cambiar mediante codigo el icono por ejemplo:
Apretar en un boton del content_main del activity que haga que se cambie el icono en el navigation, no se si me explico bien, no hacer click en el item del navigation drawer para que cambie a verificado.